# WordPress Walker - Group two items?

Tags: menus, walker, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the built-in WordPress `wp_nav_menu()` and a custom walker to loop through items for a footer nav menu. I understand that a Walker essentially loops through a nav menu, formatting each element accordingly.

For items with a sub-nav, I'd like them to be contained in a `<li class='col-sm-2'></li>` element. If the nav item does not have a subnav menu, I'd like it to be grouped in a single `<li class='col-sm-2'></li>` element. The output should be similar to this (edited in Chrome dev tools):

[image]

The only problem I'm having is that it's creating a new list item for each main nav link. Here's the code for the walker I'm using:

```
class footer_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    // add classes to ul sub-menus
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth ) {
        // depth dependent classes
        $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
        $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
        $classes = array(
            'sub-menu',
            ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
            ( $display_depth >= 2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
            'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
        );

        $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

        // build html
        $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
    }

    // add main/sub classes to li's and links
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

        // depth dependent classes
        $depth_classes = array(
            ( $depth == 0 ? 'main-menu-item' : 'sub-menu-item' ),
            ( $depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu-item' : '' ),
            ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
            'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
        );

        $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

        // passed classes
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

        if($depth == 0 && in_array('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes))  {
            // build html
            $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-' . $item->ID . '" class="col-sm-2 ' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '"><i class="fa fa-plus pull-right white hidden-lg hidden-md footer-nav__plus js-footer-nav"></i>';
        } else {
            // build html
            $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-' . $item->ID . '" class="col-sm-2 ' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';
        }

        // link attributes
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ' class="menu-link ' . ( $depth > 0 ? 'sub-menu-link' : 'main-menu-link' ) . '"';

        $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
            $args->before,
            $attributes,
            $args->link_before,
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
            $args->link_after,
            $args->after
        );

        // build html
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!